# fabricjs how to see if object src is raster or vectorized

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am creating a function, that, if the object image source is vectorized I will make it larger by scaling it up. But if the image is raster I will use a machine learning model "super resolution" to scale it up.

Currently in the code below I am using `toDataURL` to return a rasterized version of the image every time, however, to achieve the goal above, I would like to know how to first identify the "type" of the object `src`, if it is raster or vectorized.

```
const stringifiedObjectJson = JSON.stringify(obj), fabric.util.enlivenObjects([JSON.parse(json)], function (objects) {
  objects.forEach(function (o) {
    o.top -= bound.top;
    o.left -= bound.left;
    canvas.add(o);
  });
  canvas.renderAll();
  return canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To see if an object's source is raster or vectorized in Fabric.js, you can use the **type** property of the object. The type property returns a string that indicates the class name of the object, such as "image", "path", "circle", etc.

### Explanation

Fabric.js is a JavaScript library that allows you to create and manipulate canvas elements with an object-oriented approach. Fabric.js provides various classes to represent different types of objects, such as images, paths, shapes, text, etc. Each object has a set of properties and methods that define its appearance and behavior on the canvas.

One of the properties that every object has is the **type** property, which returns a string that indicates the class name of the object. For example, if you create an image object with the following code:

```py
var img = new fabric.Image(imageElement, {
  left: 100,
  top: 100
});
```

You can access the type property of the img object like this:

```py
console.log(img.type); // prints "image"
```

The type property can help you determine if an object's source is raster or vectorized, because different types of objects have different sources. For example, an image object has a raster source, which is a bitmap image that can be loaded from a URL, a data URL, or an HTML element. A path object has a vector source, which is a series of commands that define a shape using SVG syntax. A circle object also has a vector source, which is a simple geometric shape defined by a radius and a center point.

### Examples

Here are some examples of how to use the type property to see if an object's source is raster or vectorized in Fabric.js:

- Create a path object from an SVG string and log its type:

```py
var path = new fabric.Path('M 0 0 L 100 100 Q 200 100 300 0 Z', {
  fill: 'red',
  stroke: 'black'
});
console.log(path.type); // prints "path"
```

- Create a circle object with a given radius and log its type:

```py
var circle = new fabric.Circle({
  radius: 50,
  fill: 'blue',
  left: 200,
  top: 200
});
console.log(circle.type); // prints "circle"
```

- Load an image from a URL and log its type:

```py
fabric.Image.fromURL('https://example.com/image.jpg', function(img) {
  console.log(img.type); // prints "image"
});
```